# my koi are dying one after the other,and i do not know why

Tags: fish

have a koi pond 3 ft by 4/8 have lost 5 koi this week ,also have had a lot of rain ,is there  a connection,these koi are about a foot long ,had them about 8 years,filters are running right,and will moss cause a problem it right under the water fall.did a 25% water change ,added some nitraban ,nitrate was at160,ph level was6.2,anybody have an answer.

Comment: can you please add the result of your water test nitrite and ammonia.moss is harmless but it show that you have a low PH in your water,this is not a problem as long as the PH is stabile.

Comment: Just to sanity check: Are they dying or being eaten? Friends found that for the first several years, what they thought was a koi pond was actually a raccoon feeder....